# ConTeXt: How to create nice-looking fractions

Tags: context, unicode, fractions

## Background

Looking to create vulgar fractions in the current font such those in [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bc/index.htm). LaTeX has the *nicefrac* package that provides, as the name implies, fractions where the dividing line is a "nice looking" slash, rather than a horizontal line.

## Question

How do you produce a vulgar fraction in ConTeXt?

Comment: Why not just type the unicode character (or use `\char` syntax)?

Comment: Unicode does not encode all possible vulgar fractions.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Arbitrary vulgar fractions can be encoded using FRACTION SLASH (U+2044). For example: 217⁄712. Software that deals with text can choose to treat/render such text appropriately, but this might not be widely supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\vfrac`, simple as that.

```
\starttext
test \vfrac{1}{2} test \vfrac{123}{456} test
\stoptext
```